# Any program that use Java needs to be run under sudo?

Tags: java, sudo

I have installed a program that needs Java and I've changed to different Java runtime (Oracle). Now every use of java needs to be run from the terminal under `sudo`.

I needs to make it to use Java compiler without `sudo`

Comment: How did you change Java? Could you please execute just `java -version` in terminal without `sudo` and add output to your answer

Answer (score -1):

If you can only access *javac* (the java compiler) with sudo access you might have permissions issues. The following command should do it for you:

```
sudo chmod +x  `which javac`
```

Comment: Almost everything that starts with `sudo chmod 777` is a bad idea

Comment: you are right. I did some changes could you evaluate my answer again?